# How to export all dependency external libraries into a folder in eclipse automatically

Tags: eclipse, export, external, dependencies

I want to copy all external dependency libraries to a directory, but I don't want to do this job manually, since there are quite lot of libraries. I wonder if there is a way to let the eclipse do it for me automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with the [Fat Jar Eclipse Plug-in](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).

You should probably consider start using [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Fat jar may help me in the future, but it's not what I need right now

Answer (score 0):

I've written a perl script to do it for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;

my $path = $ARGV[0];
my $outputdir = $ARGV[1];
open(CLASSPATH, "<$path") or die "can't open $path";

my @lines = <CLASSPATH>;
close(CLASSPATH);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ m/<classpathentry kind="lib" path="(.*?)".*?\/>/) {
        print "copying".$1."\n";
        copy($1, $outputdir.basename($1)) or print "failed to copy $1\n";
    }
}
```

usage example:
  perl export-jar.pl [eclipse-classpath-file] [export-dir]